# Access value of struct data member from other file

Tags: c, inheritance, struct, polymorphism

I have a data member in computer.h called "status" that I calculate a value for in computer.c. I would like to access this exact value and print it in a different file called display.c.

The problem is I'm not exactly sure how I can access that variable. I'm not allowed to change the parameters of display_status() and I'm assuming creating a new computer_data struct to access the status member in that function will just create a new local variable and won't work.

I'm not exactly sure how I can access the value of computer_data->status in display.c and would appreciate any help. Would I create a getter function for status specifically or something?

computer.h

```
struct computer_data {
    struct param *status;
}
```

computer.c

```
static void computer_assign_status(){

    struct computer_data *computer = computer_get_data();

    computer->status = calculateStat();
}
```

display.c

```
#include "computer.h"

void display_status(){

    struct computer_data *computer = computer_get_data();
    
    printf("computer->status: %d /n", computer->status);

}
```

Note: Also computer_get_data() as a function is defined as "struct computer_data *computer_get_data()"

Comment: Where is `computer_get_dat` defined and declared?

Comment: computer_get_data() is defined and declared in computer.c

Comment: Yes, display.c also includes computer.h

Answer (score 0):

Using a get function is a good start. You just have to make it known in the other file.

In `computer.h` add a declaration:

```c
struct computer_data {
    struct param *status;
}

struct computer_data *computer_get_data(void);
```

Then you can use it in `display.c`.

But, of course for printing `status` you cannot use `%d` format specifier as it is a pointer to a struct.

Also in `computer.c` you have an error:

```c
struct void computer_assign_status(){
```

That should just be `void` as return type.

> Would I create a getter function for status specifically or something?

This totally depends on your needs. If you want to hide everything else that might be in that struct from a caller, then you might provide a function only returning pointer to the status part. Otherwise you can just do it as now where you return pointer to whole data struct.

Answer (score 0):

None of your examples accesses any data defined in another compilation unit. BTW your examples are written sloppy:  as an example `struct void`. Put some more effort when asking questions here

You can only access **global** (more precisely static storage with external linkage) variables defined in other compilation units.

in computer.h

```
struct computer_data {
    struct param *status;
}

extern struct computer_data computer;
```

in computer.c

```
#include "computer.h"

struct computer_data computer;

void computer_assign_status(void)
{
    computer.status = calculateStat();
}
```

in display.c

```
#include "computer.h"

void display_status()
{
    printf("computer->status: %d /n", computer.status);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In `display.c` do:

```c
extern struct computer_data * computer = computer_get_data()
```

instead.

This works because with the `extern` keyword the compiler you're using will be forced to look for the variable in an *external* file.

Comment: It's giving the errors "computer" has both 'extern' and initializer, as well as initializer element is not constant for computer_data. But then removing the = computer_get_data() gives the error "undefined reference to 'computer'"

Comment: That does not make sense. Declaring a variable as `extern` and providing an initializer at the same time does not go together.